# Large Text File Comparison Python using haslib

Tags: python, hash, compare, text-files, md5

I am new to python and leaning as fast as possible. I am trying to compare two large text files which are not sorted, so I have to compare two ways .i.e. A-B and B-A. File size is very large so I am trying to use hash method.

**Actual requirement:**
1. Compare both delimited text file .i.e. A-B and B-A. Compare like Vlookup in excel
2. write mismatched line into a text file

**Problem:**
I am able to get the hash values for each line but I have a problem in comparing both files and writing a actual mismatched line (not the hash value) into a text file.

**Code:**

```
from hashlib import sha1
import csv

File1 = 'text1.txt'
File2 = 'text2.txt'
output = 'output.txt'

with open(File1, 'r') as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            line = line.rstrip()
            digest = sha1(line).hexdigest()

with open(File2, 'r') as ifile1:
    for line1 in ifile1:
        line1 = line1.rstrip()
        digest1 = sha1(line1).hexdigest()

        writer = csv.writer(open(output, "w"))
        for i in digest:
            for xl in digest1:
                if i[0] == xl[0]:
                    i.append(xl[1:])
                    writer.writerow(i)
                digest.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hash is not designed for changes detection, but for equality check. Every change of a bit must result in a change for at least half the hash's bits.

If you could detect the differences in two streams using their hashes, you could crack passwords by computing a different hash and using that method to determine which parts of the guessed password should be changed.

You should iterate the files line by line, until you encounter a change.